# French: "triangle rectangle" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, shapes

How could I say "triangle rectangle" in English? For non-french people, it's a triangle which has an angle of 90°.

Comment: ***A right triangle*** (American English) or ***right-angled triangle*** (British English): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle

Comment: Ok, more right-angled triangle for me so. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Xanne An "isosceles triangle" is one which has two sides of equal length. This may or may not be a right-angled triangle. An "equilateral triangle" has all three sides of the same length, but cannot have a right angle. All three angles are equal and all are of 60°.

Comment: Oh, right you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [comment, user240918 wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503118/frtriangle-rectangle-in-english#comment1215426_503118):

> A right triangle (American English) or right-angled triangle (British English): [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle)